# What are the IIS sc-win32-status codes?

Tags: iis, iis-7

**Background:** I have a code of 64 in my IIS logs which I think are client disconnects whilst uploading large files. I also get some `ComExceptions` with the same status code which I have gathered are pretty much the same issue. Given the infrequency of these issues I've decided these are only to be expected and are not a problem but it did give rise to this question:

**Question:**
What is the list of possible win32 status codes? particularly the ones that can end up in IIS logs?

Comment: There is an explanation of 64 sc-win32-status code [here][1].


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/52872/iis-logs-show-sc-win32-status-64-but-only-through-some-networks

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Here's the list of all Win32 error codes. You can use this page to lookup the error code mentioned in IIS logs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381.aspx 
You can also use command line utility `net` to find information about a Win32 error code. The syntax would be:
`net helpmsg Win32_Status_Code`