# What does each sc-win32-status code indicate?

Tags: iis, iis-6, error-code, iis-logs

In my IIS log I see many instances of sc-bytes=0.

The time-taken for these entries are generally higher than average.
I can see various values of sc-win32-status like 64, 22, 121, 1236 etc.
Most of them have sc-status 200. Few have sc-win32-status 400.

Now I want to analyse each situation to figure out what happened in IIS.
But this [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382.aspx) gave only the error name and not a detail about when they can occur.
I found a good article [here](http://www.it-notebook.org/iis/article/scwin32status_64_scstatus_200.htm) which gave a good scenario description for sc-win32-status = 64 and sc-status = 200 with high time-taken.

I wanted a similar explanation for all sc-win32-status.
Is there any site which gives details about scenario for sc-win32-status codes?

Else can anybody explain when do we get following values for sc-win32-status:
64, 22, 121, 1236.

Comment: They are all network related errors; 1236 is `The network connection was aborted by the local system` [you can look up their names w/ `net helpmsg 1236`] so there is an issue with iis communicating with clients, you will have to identify the problem on your network

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex. As I mentioned in the question, I can get all the error messages from the MSDN site or the same from net helpmsg as you mentioned. But that is not enough for me to understand the situation. I needed details about various scenario in which we can get each of these error codes. This will help me in determining what could have actually happened with IIS. Please refer  to one of the sample sites I mentioned in the question for the kind of answer I am looking for.

Comment: This question should be merged with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223446/iis-sc-win32-status-codes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS sc-win32-status codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223446/iis-sc-win32-status-codes)

Answer (score 3):

The IIS Server status codes that you find in the logs are informational and are intended to provide what went wrong in certain requests/responses not why. So when you see an error code like 1326 that simply means that the username and password are not correct etc.

If you want to dig deeper and see why something happens in the background, tools like [Debug Diagnostic Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26798) and [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009) can help you out to perform analysis.